# class method hook decorator in python2

Tags: python

I have a problem with decorating a native list methods with 'post hook' functions. I need a decorator that takes as an argument a native list method and after call of the method it is supposed to run also a code of function that is being decorated.
This piece of code works okay:

```python
def _add_hook(clsmtd, info_fcn):
    def hooked(s, *p, **k):
        ret = clsmtd(s, *p, **k)
        '''some magic happens here'''
        print info_fcn(s, *p, **k)
        return ret
    return hooked

def reporting_list_deco(cls):
    def append_info(s, *p, **k):
        return 'append to %s' % s._name
    cls.append = _add_hook(cls.append, append_info)

    def remove_info(s, idx, *p, **k):
        return 'removin %s[%s]' % (s._name, idx) 
    cls.remove = _add_hook(cls.remove, remove_info)

    def setitem_info(s, idx, *p, **k):
        return 'setitem %s[%s]' % (s._name, idx)
    cls.__setitem__ = _add_hook(cls.__setitem__, setitem_info)
    ''' and so on also for pop, sort, insert, reverse and extend '''
    return cls

def test_reporting_list():
    @reporting_list_deco
    class reportin_list(list):
        def __init__(self, *p, **k):
            super(reportin_list, self).__init__(*p, **k)
            self._name = 'foo'
    rl = reportin_list([6,6,6])
    rl[1] = 1
    rl.append(7)
    rl.remove(1)
    ''' outputs:
        setitem foo[1]
        append to foo
        removin foo[1]
    '''
```

But I would like to write it like that:

```
def better_reporting_list_deco(cls):
    @_add_hook_for(cls.append)
    def append_info(s, *p, **k):
        return 'append to %s' % s._name

    @_add_hook_for(cls.remove)
    def remove_info(s, idx, *p, **k):
        return 'removin %s[%s]' % (s._name, idx) 

    @_add_hook_for(cls.__setitem__)
    def setitem_info(s, idx, *p, **k):
        return 'setitem %s[%s]' % (s._name, idx)

    return cls
```

The problem is that I don't know how to write the `_add_hook_for` decorator. Please advice.

Comment: You could maybe do it as `@_add_hook_for(cls, 'append')`, by it seems like an odd use of a decorator.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Good point. But almost each of the native methods has a different interface and reporting functions takes different arguments.

Comment: Is this always applied to built-in types? Then I can make this work with the same code for both Python 2 and 3 :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, it's only for list and dict.

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson: actually, that question is moot, because that'd be the wrong target to poke the decorators on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a decorator factory. You do *have* to pass in the class, as you can't reliably retrieve that otherwise (you are passing in methods from a *parent* class, so even if we managed to retrieve the context we'd use the wrong target class):

```
def _add_hook_for(cls, target):
    def hook_decorator(hook):
        def hooked(s, *p, **k):
            ret = target(s, *p, **k)
            # some magic happens here
            print hook(s, *p, **k)
            return ret
        setattr(cls, target.__name__, hooked)
        return hook
    return hook_decorator
```

Your class decorator then becomes:

```
def better_reporting_list_deco(cls):
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.append)
    def append_info(s, *p, **k):
        return 'append to %s' % s._name

    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.remove)
    def remove_info(s, idx, *p, **k):
        return 'removing %s[%s]' % (s._name, idx) 

    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.__setitem__)
    def setitem_info(s, idx, *p, **k):
        return 'setitem %s[%s]' % (s._name, idx)

    return cls
```

Demo:

```
>>> @better_reporting_list_deco
... class reporting_list(list):
...     def __init__(self, *p, **k):
...         super(reporting_list, self).__init__(*p, **k)
...         self._name = 'foo'
...
>>> rl = reporting_list([6, 6, 6])
>>> rl[1] = 1
setitem foo[1]
>>> rl.append(7)
append to foo
>>> rl.remove(1)
removing foo[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @martijn-pieters I rewrote it like that (works well in Python 2.7):

```
def _add_hook_for(cls, target):
    def hook_decorator(hook):
        def hooked(s, *p, **k):
            ret = target(s, *p, **k)
            # some magic happens here
            print(hook(s, target.__name__, *p, **k))
            return ret
        setattr(cls, target.__name__, hooked)
        return hook
    return hook_decorator

def reporting_list_deco(cls):
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.append)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.extend)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.sort)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.reverse)
    def no_idx_info(s, op, *p, **k):
        return '%s %s' % (op, s._name)

    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.__setitem__)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.insert)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.__delitem__)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.remove)
    @_add_hook_for(cls, cls.pop)
    def idx_info(s, op, idx='', *p, **k):
        return '%s %s[%s]' % (op, s._name, idx) 
    return cls

def test_reporting_list():
    @reporting_list_deco
    class reporting_list(list):
        def __init__(self, name, *p, **k):
            super(reporting_list, self).__init__(*p, **k)
            self._name = name

    rl = reporting_list('foo', [61,62,63])
    rl[1] = 1
    rl.append(7)
    rl.remove(1)
    rl.extend([5,6,7])
    rl.pop()
    rl.pop(2)
    rl.sort()
    del rl[0]
    rl.reverse()
    print(rl)
```

outputs:

```
__setitem__ foo[1]
append foo
remove foo[1]
extend foo
pop foo[]
pop foo[2]
sort foo
__delitem__ foo[0]
reverse foo
[63, 61, 6]
```

It can be also applied to a dict. Thank you Martijn!